# Rebuild a Source RPM on CentOS 7

Tags: centos, rpmbuild

I haven't had success building any SRPM on CentOS 7. Following instructions from https://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/RebuildSRPM

Output from `rpmbuild --rebuild man-db-2.6.3-11.el7.src.rpm` : https://pastebin.com/00X2mjjQ

Output from `rpmbuild --rebuild htop-2.2.0-3.el7.src.rpm`: https://pastebin.com/3dqkB5UN

What am I missing?

Comment: strange, your commands seem fine, maybe something is broken on your machine?

Comment: I'm using the lastest version of gcc, amongst other things.

Comment: When you say "latest version of `gcc`", do you mean you built new RPMs, or you are fully up-to-date with what CentOS offers? Because if it is the former, the specfiles from CentOS might have certain flags, etc, that don't work on later versions of `gcc` (or more likely don't set compatibility flags for the older `gcc` used with CentOS).

Comment: @AaronD.Marasco I cloned gcc from its official git repo, compiled it and replaced the existing system binaries. Generally speaking it did not cause any particularly problem except for rebuilding SRPM.

Comment: Then I would try stock build chains and see what happens. To have newer `gcc` on the machine, you should check out [SCL](https://www.softwarecollections.org/en/).

Comment: @AaronD.Marasco someone on Reddit helped me to use mock, which download, set up and build SRPM using stock toolchain. Might work with SCL as well. Unfortunately, it kinda defeats the point to use a newer toolchain. Major components (kernel, glib, etc) are rebuilt using the newer toolchain. Any idea?

Comment: You'd have to update the specfiles to use the newest toolchain options properly, something usually done by the package maintainer. A good start would be looking at the Fedora Rawhide specs for the package and comparing that to what CentOS provides.

Comment: Thank you! I will investigate.